# League of Legends: Does entering stealth during the start of the animation of an enemy spell/auto attack cancel them?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering if it's possible to cancel enemy auto attacks with vayne by ulting and then waiting for the enemy auto attack animation to start and them q immediately.

Is this even possible and how many things can you cancel this way?

EDIT:
I am interested what happens if you cancel if you go in stealth during the enemy windup animation (also if it is cancelled, what happens to the internal enemy auto attack timer, does it stay at 0, as if the auto never happened or does it set to the usual timer)

There are 3 phases of an auto attack:
- windup, the animation at the beginning of it
- shooting, the animation when the projectile is created
- resetting animation, the character figure returns to the idle animation

I may have the phases wrong, please correct me if I do.

Comment: As for auto attacks, it just depends on the timing. If you go invisible during the windup but before the attack actually occurs you can cancel it. See the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Basic_attack#General). This should also be true for point and click spells but the wiki page for stealth doesn't have any information on the subject.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill yeah I am curious about doing it during the windup. Thank you for your information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going into stealth does not cancel any targeted abilities that are already travelling. So if an auto attack is in the air, that auto is going to hit, regardless of whether you stealth or not. The same thing happens with actual abilities as well, including: Brand ult, Janna W, Shaco E, Malphite Q, and others.

If you're looking for something that will outright cancel these types of abilities, either a spell shield (such as Nocturne's W or Sivir's E) will block abilities, and Zhonya's will cancel any auto attacks currently travelling to you.

Stealthing before the auto attack actually goes off will prevent the auto attack from firing, since the enemy cannot target you anymore. The timing for that is very precise though, similar to stutter-stepping/kiting. You can test this with any champion by going into the practice tool and getting the caster minions to aggro to you. Once they start shooting projectiles, walk into a bush. You'll see that if you time it right, they'll wind up their attack and then cancel it once you walk into a bush. Any autos that were already in the air will still hit you though.

Comment: A few more examples: Jax E, Pantheon passive and Shen W block autos of all kinds,  Yasuo W and Braum E block projectiles including autos, Xin Zhao R blocks all damage from outside its radius.

Comment: You might be able to cancel the "cast" animation for auto attacks with going into stealth. This might cause an auto attack to fly, but deal no damage at all. This is more likely to happen if the opponent keeps clicking onto you for the auto attacks, but will still keep an very low success rate

Comment: @Mage Xy My question is about whether you can cancel the attack during the windup animation and if there is any deterministic behaviour about this.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer does this always happen? Or is it just a bug?

Comment: @klemenkobau it is a bug that was supposed to be fixed long ago. After that "fix" this bug happens much less than before, but it does still occur. I am not sure what exactly triggers it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer oh okay, thank you for your information. I'll try this in game sometime.

Comment: @klemenkobau Once the auto attack projectile is in the air, it will hit you, barring special abilities like the ones Fabian mentioned.

Comment: @MageXy yes but I am interested what happens to it if you enter stealth during the enemy auto attack windup.

Comment: @klemenkobau Stealthing *before* the auto attack actually goes off will prevent the auto attack from firing, since they cannot target you. The timing for that is very precise though. You can test this with any champion by going into the practice tool and getting the caster minions to aggro to you. Once they start shooting projectiles, walk into a bush. You'll see that if you time it right, they'll wind up their attack and then cancel it once you walk into a bush. Any autos that were already in the air will still hit you though.

Comment: @MageXy oh okay thank you, I will accept your answer, but please put this into it :D

Comment: A bit late, but if I remember well, Kalista auto attacks will fail if she don't have vision on you on hit, even if the projectile is created before you hide. (just to add another specific detail)